# Providing AWS_PROFILE when reading S3 files with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, profile, aws-credentials

I want my Spark app (Scala) to be able to read S3 files

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://my-bucket-name/my-object-key")
```

On my dev machine, I could access S3 files using awscli a pre-configured profile in `~/.aws/config` or `~/.aws/credentials`, like:

```
aws --profile my-profile s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name/my-object-key
```

But when trying to read those files from Spark, with the aws_profile provided as an env variable (*AWS_PROFILE*), I got the following error:

> doesBucketExist on my-bucket-name: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

Also tried to provide the profile as a JVM option (`-Daws.profile=my-profile`), with no luck.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to provide the spark property: `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider`, setting it to `com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider`.
If I could change the code to build the Spark Session, then something like:

```
SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider")
    .getOrCreate()
```

The other way is to provide the JVM option `-Dspark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider`.
*NOTE the prefix `spark.hadoop`

Answer (score 0):

If problems arise still after setting `fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` to `com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider` and correctly setting `AWS_PROFILE`, it might be because you're using Hadoop 2 for which the above configuration is not supported.

Therefore, the only workaround I found was to upgrade to Hadoop 3.

Check [this post](https://www.ilkkapeltola.fi/2021/04/how-to-access-aws-s3-with-pyspark.html) and Hadoop [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had two issue related to Spark+AWS compatibility.

First off, pyspark didn't see profiles specified in `~/.aws/config` file. I had to move it to `~/.aws/credentials` for spark to at least admit that the profile exists. At least from within `jupyter` and using `pyspark`.

More importantly, sso/identity server is a recommended way to access AWS from local machines, but sso-based auth setup is not supported by `s3a` connection chain. It's explained in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74061215/spark-delta-with-aws-sso/74067946#74067946) to another question.