# Spark Delta with AWS SSO

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, delta-lake

What I'm trying to do:

- read from and write to S3 buckets across multiple `AWS_PROFILE`'s

resources:

- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configuring_different_S3_buckets_with_Per-Bucket_Configuration

  - **does** show how to use different cred on per-bucket
  - **does** show how to use different credential providers
  - **doesn't** show how to use more than one AWS_PROFILE
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html#authenticating
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html
- [No FileSystem for scheme: s3 with pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740670/no-filesystem-for-scheme-s3-with-pyspark)

What I have working so far:

- AWS SSO works and i can access different resources in python via `boto3` by changing environment variable `AWS_PROFILE`
- delta spark can read and write to S3 using hadoop configurations

  - enable delta tables for pyspark

    ```py
    builder.config("spark.sql.extensions",           
        "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
        "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"))
    ```
  - allow s3 schema for read/write

    ```py
      "spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl",
      "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
    ```
  - use instance profile `AWS_PROFILE` for one or more buckets

    ```py
    "fs.s3a.bucket.{prod_bucket}.aws.credentials.provider",
    "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider"
    ```

```
any help, suggestions, comments appreciated. thanks!
```

Comment: i think i can use IAM roles to span multiple profiles? i'll try it https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/assumed_roles.html

Answer (score 3):

As of October 2022, the s3a connector doesn't support AWS SSO/identity server. Moving to the AWS SDK v2 is a prerequisite, which is a WiP.

See [HADOOP-18352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-18352)

Comment: Thank you, Steve! I should've checked more thoroughly. Appreciate all your contributions to Hadoop!

Comment: no worries. maybe if you use the sso tools on the CLI and get the credentials exported locally, you could then get the current session creds into the spark conf...